# Character change like they do in real phone messaging

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Hi everyone,
            I want to do text watcher. What I really want is that the text watcher will count the message like they do in real phone. ( e.g 1/160 160 starts decreasing with every letter I wrote in edit text and when letters are more then 160 it will become 2/160 ). What I have done is simple text watcher. With counts all the characters. Here is my code

```
  private final TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        textView2.setText(String.valueOf(s.length()));
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
```

and

```
    EditMsg.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);
```

Hope you got my question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `s.length()` in `onTextChanged` is what you want

Comment: use arithmetic operations `%` and/or `/`, they are very powerful and will allow you to do this

Comment: any reference code ??

Comment: who voted it As negative ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out in onTextChanged()

```
int length = s.length();
textView2.setText(String.valueOf(length/160 + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(160 - length%160));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want message count. Use this:

```
int value = (s.length()/160) + 1; 
or
int value = s.length()%160;
```